# substrings in javascript are processing different on android device than on my desktop-pc

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, substring

I am encountering a strange problem when I want to use my webapplication on my android Phone. I have been busy scripting an application that implements the google-maps distance matrix. When the user types in two different zip-codes the application connects to google maps and calculates the travel-distance between these points. For example when I type: 4701JX in the first textfield and 4731JD in the second textfield (these are dutch zip-codes) google maps calculates the distance and and displays the distance into a third table column. The result is 13,5 km. In order to calculate the total distance when multiple distances have been calculated I need to convert this string to a Double, therefore I scripted the following:

```js
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
       
var dist_without_km = function()
{
  var dist = distance.substr(0,(distance.length-2));
  var commaIndex = dist.search(",");       
  var wl = dist.substr(0,(commaIndex));
  var dc = dist.substr((commaIndex+1),dist.length-1);
        
 var wldc = wl + "." + dc;      
 var sub = wldc.substr(1,wldc.length);
        
 total_kilometers+=Math.round(parseFloat(sub));
        
        
 $("#tot_km").html(total_kilometers);
 $("#kmTot").val(Math.round(total_kilometers));
        
 return sub;
}
       
$("#table tr:nth-child("+childIndex+") td:nth-child(3)").html(dist_without_km);
```

On my desktop-pc browser this script works fine. 13,5 km is succesfully converted to 13.5. But If I connect to my webserver on my android Phone and I open the application 13,5 km will be converted to 3.5 which doesn't provide valid data. On both devices (PC and Android Phone) I am using google chrome.

Could anyone explain to me what problem I'm facing?
Thanks in advance!

regards Tim

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
var sub = wldc.substr(1,wldc.length);
```

This chops off the first character of the string, which on mobile is presumably `13,5`, but on a PC there is an extra leading character that you have found you need to discard.

How I would approach this would be to use a regular expression like:

```
var sub = distance.replace(/[^\d]*(\d+)\,(\d+).*/, '$1.$2');
```

This will skip any non-digit at the start of the string and everything after the fractional distance, and replace the comma with a decimal point. This replaces the first six lines of code.

(Note that I'm not happy with this approach, and it will break if someone has their fractions separator set to `.`, such as in the UK and US locales)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed google-maps has two different ways to output the amount of km depending on whether you use a mobile device or desktop-pc. Now my code works fine!